# Как сделать фиксированное кол-во знаков после запятой при записи числа в переменную?

Tags: c++

У меня есть число, которое нужно перевести в строку и записать в QLabel с указанной пользователем точностью. У меня есть только способ как установить точность вывода cout. Но в приложении Qwindgets нужен другой способ. Подскажите как это можно сделать. Пользуюсь QT, компилятор MiniGW

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_res_clicked()
{
    QString res;
    res += "Ответ: ";
    double a,b,c;
    a = p1;
    b = p2;
    c = p3;
    double D = pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);
    if (D > 0){
        double tmp = (-b + sqrt(D))/(2*a);
        res += QString::number(tmp);
        res += "; ";
        tmp = (-b - sqrt(D))/(2*a);
        res += QString::number(tmp);
    }
    else{
        if (fabs(D) == 0){
            res += QString::number((-b/(2*a)));
        }
        else{
            res += "Нет решения.";

        }
    }
    ui->label_res->setText(res);
}
```

Comment: QString{ "%1" }.arg( 12.34, 6, 'f', 2, '0' ) https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-9

Comment: У меня есть переменная eps_value(вводится пользователем), и tmp -(вычисляется по некоторому выражению). Как мне записать в QLabel значение tmp с eps_value знаков после запятой?

Comment: приведите код )

Comment: подалуйста вставьте код в сообщение

Comment: добавил код к вопросу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res += QString::number(tmp);
```

заменить на:

```
res += QString::number(tmp, 'g', eps_value);
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#argument-formats